# mkdir() php function issue

Tags: php, html, directory

index.php

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="createfolder.php" method="post" >
        <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="center">Please write gallery name and description</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Name </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="gname" id="text" value=""></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><textarea name="gdescription" cols="30" rows="5" id="textarea"></textarea></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

createfolder.php

```
    <?php

$name = $_POST['gname'];
$dirPath = "images/".$name;
$result = mkdir($dirPath, 0755);
if ($result == 1) {
    echo $dirPath . " has been created";
} else {
    echo $dirPath . " has NOT been created";
}
?>
```

having problems making the directory. error:
[image: this is the error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because there is no file in directory user

`file_exists` — Checks whether a file or directory exists and

`is_dir` — Tells whether the filename is a directory

```
  if (is_dir("path") === true ){
                echo "DIRECTORY: ".$entry."\n";
            }
```

or

```
$filename = '/path/foo.txt';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mkdir( $dirPath, 0755, true );`

The third parameter will recursively create the containing directories as well.

Answer (score 0):

`mkdir()` has a third argument, `$recursive`, which will ensure that the full path exists. Replace this:

```
$result = mkdir($dirPath, 0755);
```

with:

```
$result = mkdir($dirPath, 0755, true);
```

And it should work just fine.